# JQuery AJAX and OOP JS Scope Woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop, scope

So, I created an object which makes an AJAX call to populate its properties during the initialization phase.  However, I am running into a very weird behaviour: I can print and see the property values fine within the $.ajax() scope, but any public method that returns the value of properties have a return value of "undefined".

Here's what the JS code looks like:

```
function MyFunction() {
   this.myProperty;
   this.init();
}

Myfunction.prototype.getPropertyValue = function () {
    alert(this.myProperty); // returns 'undefined'
}

Myfunction.prototype.init = function () { 
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: "getProperty.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
         this.myProperty = response[0].Property;
         alert(this.myProperty) // returns 'Property Name'
      }
   });
}
```

My thinking is that within the $.ajax() scope, 'this' is actually referring to something else.  So, my question is how do I make sure that 'this.myProperty' is set and doesn't lose its value once we get outside of the AJAX scope?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the reason why you're getting "undefined" because of the way you establish the value:

```
var MyFunction = function () {
   this.myProperty;
   alert(this.myProperty); // undefined!
   this.init();
};
```

When you declare properties (or variables) without specifying a value, they default to "undefined". Instead:

```
var MyFunction = function () {
   this.myProperty = false;
   alert(this.myProperty); // false
   this.init();
};
```

On to the ajax call. You are right that the scope of the callback is not the same as the object. `this`, in the ajax success function, refers to the jQuery-wrapped XHR object. When you call `this.myProperty = response[0].Property`, you are actually creating a new property on the ajax object and setting **its** value. To correct this, you can either use the `context` option of the jQuery ajax object, OR bind the callback function using the javascript `bind` method:

```
  success: function(response) {
     this.myProperty = response[0].Property;
  }.bind(this)
```

... or:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: "getProperty.php",
      dataType: "json",
      context: this,
      success: function(response) {
         this.myProperty = response[0].Property;
      }
   });
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SnLmu/

**Documentation**

- `bind()` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- `jQuery.ajax()` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- *Functions and Function Scope* on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: How do I handle the race condition then?  Because now, the value is 'false' (which makes sense). 

Is there a way to force the AJAX call to run synchronously?  (async:false is depecrated since 1.8, from what I know)

Comment: @steacha Javascript is not multi-threaded and lacks a `sleep` function, so a "synchronous" call only means that you block until it is done. Blocking in javascript is blocking in the worst way -- the UI will be locked and the page unresponsive. You might even trigger the "this script is taking too long" warning if your blocking loop is too tight (like `while(!$condition) { continue; }`, for example). You should use a callback function instead -- an ajax call in an object constructor is probably not the most reliable way to build your class because of this limitation.

Comment: @steacha See: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX for ideas, but you see there he mentions that the UI will be blocked. Also see the docs for XMLHttpRequest - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XMLHttpRequest -- you *can* specify that your request should be synchronous, just not using jQuery's `ajax()`

Comment: A callback function like adeneo suggested below?

Comment: (FYI, "above" and "below" changes each time you load the page, when answers have the same vote count) adeneo's suggested route is one of several ways that you can approach the problem, depending on how you're going to use the class. If you want to call the `getPropertyValue` method as soon as possible, you could put it in the `success` callback, or pass it as a constructor argument, or set it on a timer.... there are many methods, depending on how you're going to use this class. With all respect to adeneo's solution, it does make assumptions based on guesswork; you've not given any context.

Comment: @steacha tagging you for the comment above, but I also wanted to point out that the object shown in adeneo's answer is not the same thing as the object you show in your question. Your prototype-based object has a special set of considerations and gotchyas, so it is with the the object literal approach. Both are valid, it really depends on what the object is going to do and how you're going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that the ajax is asynchronous so the properties may not be set when you try to access them (race condition). The other is the value of `this` inside of the ajax call is not `Myfunction`. You can fix by:

```
Myfunction.prototype.init = function () { 
   var that = this;
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: "getProperty.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
         that.myProperty = response[0].Property;
         alert(that.myProperty) // returns 'Property Name'
      }
   });
}
```

or you can use the `context` setting in the ajax call. Per the [site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will
>   make that the context for the complete callback of a request, like so:

```
Myfunction.prototype.init = function () { 
       var that = this;
       $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: "getProperty.php",
          dataType: "json",
          context: Myfunction,
          success: function(response) {
             this.myProperty = response[0].Property;
             alert(this.myProperty) // returns 'Property Name'
          }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyFunction = {
    myProperty: null,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.ajax(function(response) {
            self.myProperty = response;
            self.secondfunction(self.myProperty); //call next step only when ajax is complete
        });
    },
    ajax: function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "getProperty.php",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
            callback(response[0].Property);
        });
    },
    secondfunction: function(prop) {
        alert(prop);
    }
}

$(function() {    
    MyFunction.init();
});
```

Comment: Just a note: this object is not equivalent to the object in the OP's code. Both are completely valid approaches, and depending on the use-case, either one may be appropriate. This is an object literal, the question code shows a prototype-based object.

Comment: @chris - You are of course right, this is not a prototype based answer, and I did start typing something with prototype, but based on the way the the init() function was setup and the ajax call that most likely would require a callback, it seemed like an object literal would be more appropriate, and that's how I would have done it, so I decided to show how to do it this way instead ?