# How to use class variable in a ajax callback?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I would like to know how I can access my class variable inside my ajax callback

```
success: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            this.baralho = obj.countBaralho;
```

My Class

```
var Placar = {
    descarte : 0,
    jogador1: 0,
    jogador2: 0,
    baralho: 0,

    fetchFromServer: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'get-placar',
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                this.baralho = obj.countBaralho;
                this.descarte = obj.countDescarte;
                this.jogador1 = obj.numCartas1;
                this.jogador2 = obj.numCartas2;
            }
        });

    },

    update: function() {
        $('#num-cartas-1').html(this.jogador1);
        $('#num-cartas-2').html(this.jogador2);
        $('#cartas-restantes').html(this.baralho);
        $('#num-cartas-descarte').html(this.descarte);
    }

}
```

The values aren't being setted from the server, How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery AJAX and OOP JS Scope Woes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975332/jquery-ajax-and-oop-js-scope-woes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` in the ajax's success function is not your object(its probably an XMLHttpRequest object).

I would use a constructor to create the object instead of an object literal, and create a closure to be able to access the object in any context.

```
var Placar = new (function(){
    this.descarte = 0;
    this.jogador1 = 0;
    this.jogador2 = 0;
    this.baralho = 0;
            var self = this;        
    this.fetchFromServer = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'get-placar',
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                self.baralho = obj.countBaralho;
                self.descarte = obj.countDescarte;
                self.jogador1 = obj.numCartas1;
                self.jogador2 = obj.numCartas2;
            }
        });

    };

    this.update = function() {
        $('#num-cartas-1').html(self.jogador1);
        $('#num-cartas-2').html(self.jogador2);
        $('#cartas-restantes').html(self.baralho);
        $('#num-cartas-descarte').html(self.descarte);
    };

})();
```